# Working with Firestore documents and collection data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a few documents with the following collection structure in Firestore

```
_fl_meta_: Object { createdBy: "Kz5vTvzlmGhRCxqKuDhrvvANqPe2", docId: "76qlSYWItERvJVnLKSDt", env: "production", … }
author: "asd"
content: "last 1"
date: "2019-06-19T12:00:00-07:00"
id: "76qlSYWItERvJVnLKSDt"
imageDeck: Array [ {…} ]
order: 0
parentId: 0
status: "published"
summary: "last 1"
title: "last 1"
```

im trying to loop thru my documents and render its collection data to my components but im having issues.

my `query`

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db
  .collection('fl_content')
  .where('_fl_meta_.schema', '==', 'blog')
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data());
      // let results = Object.keys(doc.data()).map(function (key) {
      //   return [String(key), doc.data()[key]];
      // })
      // this.setState({ cards: results });
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
```

that query outputs the above collection from `firestore`. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your `querySnapshot` and map it to result in an array of objects containing  your documents.

```
const querySnapshot = firebase.firestore().collection('fl_content')
  .where('_fl_meta_.schema', '==', 'blog').get()

.then((querySnapshot) => {
  // The following line will result in an array of objects (each object is your document data)
  const yourDocuments = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
  this.setState({cards: yourDocuments});
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Then you can do something like:

```
// INSIDE YOUR RENDER METHOD

const cardItems = this.state.cards.map((item,index) => 
  <CardComponent key={index}>
     {item.name} // Here you can access and display the fields of your documents
  </CardComponent>
);

return(
  <SomeContainerComponent>
     {cardItems}
  </SomeContainerComponent>
);
```

Comment: can you explain to me how this worked, still new to all of this react stuff and so confusing to me that you need to create a const to store / load a component for it to be rendered in another component.... lol...

Comment: That `cardItems` variable is storing an array with a bunch of `<CardComponent/>'s`. That is JSX markup and each elements of that array gets translated into something like this: for example `return(<div>aaa</div>);` is translated into `return React.createElement("div", null, "aaa");` which basically creates and renders that on screen. And that will happen for each element of the array `cardItems`, so all of them will be rendered accordingly. Take a look at [Introducing JSX from React DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)